# How can I apply for a visa for Chile in Nigeria?

Tags: visas, chile, nigerian-citizens

How can I apply for Chilean visa when there is no Chile embassy in Nigeria?
Do I need to travel to Cote D'Ivoire?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange! Please don't write your questions in ALL CAPS.

Comment: ARE YOU THE SAME GUY WHO INHERITED $100,000,000, BECAUSE THAT GUY ALSO USES CAPS IN HIS EMAILS.

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/tips-for-getting-a-visa-when-theres-no-embassy-in-ones-country-of-residence?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

According to the [website of the Chilean Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.minrel.gob.cl/prontus_minrel/site/artic/20080619/pags/20080619154024.php), visa applications are handled either by a consulate (embassies also act as consulates, but usually there are additional consulates) or the Department of Immigration.

There [doesn't seem to be any consulates](http://chileabroad.gov.cl/en/consulados/) near you, so you'll have to contact the Department of Immigration. The page I linked to lists a mail address and telephone number, and it also has a link that opens an email form.