# How can a Libyan get a Polish visa? The embassy is closed

Tags: visas, poland, libyan-citizens

I'm a Libyan citizen. I studied in Poland last year (2016.) My temporary resident card expired six months ago.

Unfortunately, the Polish embassy closed in Libya due to the problems in Libya.  They told me that I must go to Egypt to apply for a Polish visa. I can't get to Egypt because it's hard to get a visa to Egypt at this time.

I thought maybe I could go to Poland and show my expired student document to the  immigration border office and after explaining the problems, get a visa to enter Poland. Would that expose myself to detention or deportation?

Comment: Go to the embassy in Tunisia, you don't Need a visa there

Comment: Of related interest: *[Tips for getting a visa when there's no embassy in one's country of residence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3455)* and *[What if passport is lost and home country has no diplomatic presence?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83523/)*

Answer (score 8):

Probably not. Airlines generally refuse transport for passengers without visa, and visas on the border are the exception anyway.