# Panama, Belize, Costa Rica or Honduras Visa from Pakistan

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, panama, costa-rica, honduras

I'm a Pakistani national and trying to get a visa for Panama, Belize, Costa Rica or Honduras. How do I do this? Most of them don't have Visa services in Pakistan so where do we apply and what are the requirements? Also, I read that a visa for one of these covers the other countries as well. Is that true?

Comment: You say that _most of_ these countries don't have a visa services in Pakistan, and you don't seem to care which of the countries you get a visa for. So why not get the visa from one of the countries that _does_ have representation in Pakistan?

Comment: Where are you actually planning to go?

Comment: I am planning to see Belize / Honduras or Costa Rica / Panama , as I have a valid US visa and German residence I can travel without visa but want to take my fiancee  as well, she's currently in PK. Unfortunately non of the above have embassies in Pakistan, some people I guess go to UAE and apply from there. These countries don't have proper websites and never pick up their phone so it's totally blind

Comment: Of interest: *[Tips for getting a visa when there's no embassy in one's country of residence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3455)* ; also see *[What if passport is lost and home country has no diplomatic presence?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/83531/1480)*